# php curl json , I'm unable to post request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm new to recess framework. Some how I have created RESTful web services with json. and my URL is like this
" curl -X POST http://www.example.com/example/skill.json -d {"skill":"name":"SuckingUp","jobCategory_id":"1","creator":"dwayne@test.com"},"u":"dwayne@test.com","p":"foo"}' ".

My question is how we can implement in our code or we can call from other application or we can integrate as web service. How we can call with cURL?.

I have no idea where I have to write the code.

I got stuck, please help me let out this.

Thanks,
Soeb
You can reach me @ nasir_1823@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're looking for this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
You use that command to call cURL in the system, and pass it whatever command line arguments you wish to execute.